# CodeIgniter y Ajax con JavaScript puro cambio de valor

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Buen dia, al pasar via ajax el id, este se modifica por %20#,

Ejemplos:

Si id = 1, sale como %201

Si id = 2, sale como %202.

Por esta razon no se completa la parte dinamica en mi select, solo sale el option estatico ya que, como es evidente, no existe el id %201 en la bd.

Pude solucionarlo de manera simple, usando:

```
$id_real = intval(substr($id, 3, 1));
```

Pero me gustaria saber la razon, ya que solo me ocurre en CodeIgniter.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es un comportamiento normal de **Codeigniter** si pudieses añadir la parte del código donde capturas y envías esa **ID** podríamos ver donde está el problema. No obstante la cadena `%20` corresponde al caracter **UTF-8** del **espacio** así que la impresión que me da es que estás obteniendo ese **ID** por la **URL** y la estás tratando mal.